# Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'FormArray' angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to push formgroup in formArray at 0th index. It should be replace by 0th element in formArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by nicraft, use the [**`insert`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert) API on the [**`FormArray`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). You might have to manage the template accordingly.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      array: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  addItem() {
    const formArray  = this.array;
    formArray.insert(0, this.fb.control(formArray.length + 1));
  }

  get array() {
    return (<FormArray>this.form.get('array'));
  }
}
```

---

**NOTE:** Here I'm simply adding a new `FormControl` to the `array` `FormArray` and setting the `FormArray`'s current length + 1 as the value for it.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-control-to-first-in-form-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **FormArray [insert-anchor](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#!#insert-anchor)**

```
control.insert(index: number, control: AbstractControl): void
```